# Pattern matching over Data.Map

Tags: haskell

I did a search but, surprisingly, didn't find anything that would help me to perform pattern matching over it. I need to make sure that in my Map "variable" exactly 3 keys. That's it. Instead of "if ... then ... else", I want to go with pattern matching as it is easier to read and seems to be more haskell way. So:

```
myFunction :: Map String String
--.......................

main = do
  let var1 = myFunction
  -- how do I ensure it has exactly 3 keys in it and if not raise an error?
```

Comment: If there is anything non-Haskell-wayish then probably that you have a function that works only on maps of a certain size. Likely that your types don’t match what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pattern match on `M.toList`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
-- ...
main = do
  case (M.toList myFunction) of
    [a,b,c] -> ... -- exactly 3 arguments
    _       -> ... -- more or less than 3 arguments
```

Comment: how would I know which value corresponds to which key?

Comment: a, b and c are a tuple `(key, value)`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp You wouldn't, `Map`s do not preserve order since they use a more efficient implementation than the type `[(key, value)]`, IIRC it's a binary search tree, but then you'd have to look at the source of `toList` to figure out what order that returns in.  In short, there isn't a good way to know for sure which ones are which.  If you need that functionality, I would recommend just (looking up each element you need](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/04a56336e5917d3ec5b1).  This example will preserve order and return `Nothing` if those three keys aren't found in that `Map`.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot pattern match on abstract data types, as you don’t have access to their constructors¹, so you will have to work with the functions provided by the `Data.Map´ module.

But note that there is a `size :: Map k a -> Int` function you can use. And if you don’t like `if .. then .. else ..` (which is in no way wrong or unhaskellish), you can use pattern guards:

```
foo m | size m == 3 = ...
      | otherwise = error "Not three element"
```

¹ <sup>Disregarding view patterns and pattern synonyms here, but these are just syntactic surgar.</sup>

Comment: Normally I'd say `size` or `length` _are_ un-Haskellish, but here it's arguably the right thing to do.

Comment: why is it an abstract data type?

Comment: The module exporting the type does not also export its constructors. If if would, you could build invalid search trees and suddenly the `Map` functions would give wrong results.

Comment: All right. Is there any way to get those 3 values all at once?